# Should we rename the tag [2001] to [2001-a-space-odyssey]?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, retagging

We have the tag [2001](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2001) for questions related to Stanley Kubrick's movie *2001: A Space Odyssey*, used on 20 questions.

I propose we rename the tag to the full name of the movie — [2001-a-space-odyssey](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2001-a-space-odyssey) — since that is much clearer and make [2001](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2001) a synonym.

---

The movie and the book share the exact same title (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey), and the [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062622/) and [ISFDb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2485) entries). This is not the case with the sequel, which is called *2010: Odyssey Two* for the book and *2010* or *2010: The Year We Make Contact* for the movie.

Any ideas if and how to rename the tag [2010](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2010)?

---

[2001](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2001) is done. I'll wait a while before doing [2010](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2010) and any other related tags.

---

*Do we need a tag for the franchise?**

---

[2010](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2010) is done. I've also created a tag for *3001*, so we now have

- [2001-a-space-odyssey](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2001-a-space-odyssey)
- [2010-odyssey-two](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2010-odyssey-two)
- no tag for *2061* since [I've found no questions about it](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=2061+is%3Aquestion).
- [3001-the-final-odyssey](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3001-the-final-odyssey)

I think using [2001-a-space-odyssey](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2001-a-space-odyssey) for questions about the franchise should suffice.

*Done*.

Comment: It isn't even necessary to make the synonym, since it's inlcuded in the full title and should thus come up when typing just "2001".

Comment: Is there a way to do this in one go, or should we just edit the questions?

Comment: I believe mods can do a [tag rename](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88006/split-tag-merging-from-tag-renaming); I'm struggling to think of another use for [tag:2001], so that may be a good option (and we can always re-create [tag:2001] later if we need it - I think)

Comment: Planet of the Apes was released in 1968. In 2001 another version of the same movie (same title) was released. Might be enough to cause confusion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **Yes, we should rename [2001](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2001) to [2001-a-space-odyssey](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2001-a-space-odyssey).**

  The proposed tag is more expressive and unambiguous. (You couldn't, for example, mistake it for a year tag.)
- **We should rename [2010](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2010) to [2010-odyssey-two](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2010-odyssey-two).**

  There's very little to choose between the book or the film title. I'm inclined to lean towards the book for a few small reasons:

  - The film is based on the book, not the other way around. The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_(film)) for the film:

    > It is a sequel to Stanley Kubrick's 1968 film *2001: A Space Odyssey*, and is based on Arthur C. Clarke's novel *2010: Odyssey Two*.
  - The book titles (*2001: A Space Odyssey*, *2010: Odyssey Two*, *2061: Odyssey Three* and *3001: The Final Odyssey*) are clearly part of a common series, in a way that's less obvious from the film titles.

---

As for the mechanics, I think we should just edit the tags by hand (assuming we don't fall afoul of the "this tag is too similar to an existing tag" checks). Editing 24 questions can be done quite quickly.

Once we have the longer tags, anybody attempting to use the short version will have the longer version suggested. The benefits of a tag synonym are minimal.

Comment: Do you think we need a tag for the franchise?

Comment: Maybe editing 24 questions is fast, easy and not too intrusive, but just letting the moderators rename the tag is even faster, easier and non-intrusive.